# Unicode characters in org-mode tables

Tags: org-table, unicode

Here's an org-mode table with some unicode math characters in it:

[image]

Note that the columns don't align.

I can manually fix the issue by inserting literal tab characters after each character via `ctrl-q TAB`:

[image]

It would be nice to have a command that did this, instead of having to manually add sufficient tab characters to each cell.

Is there a good way to approach this in elisp?

Comment: Do you use a somehow special font ?  For me, simply hitting TAB in each line correctly aligns the columns.

Comment: @JeanPierre Very interesting that they align for you! I'm using Emacs on Windows. I have the following in my init file: `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Consolas" :height 100)`.

Answer (score 1):

What's probably happening is that your regular font is missing those glyphs, so they get filled in from another font, which uses a different width. Here's what `M-x describe-char` shows for me when the point is on the `a`:

```
            character: a (displayed as a) (codepoint 97, #o141, #x61)
    preferred charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV))
code point in charset: 0x61
                       ...
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    xft:-DAMA-Ubuntu Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-17-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x44)
```

and here's the `∈`:

```
            character: ∈ (displayed as ∈) (codepoint 8712, #o21010, #x2208)
    preferred charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x2208
                       ...
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    xft:-GNU -FreeSans-normal-normal-normal-*-17-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#xDC0)
```